# What is the difference between 全部作品 and 完本?

Tags: meaning

I began learning Mandarin so that I could read Chinese fantasy novels (I've read several translated ones already). I'm a little confused because on [Qidian's website](https://www.qidian.com) I see several tabs at the top, one says 全部作品 (Completed Works?) and another says 完本 (Completed Books?), am I understanding these correctly? What would be the difference between these two categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

全部作品 means all works.
完本 means completed books.

Comment: is this contextual or is there a distinct difference between 全部 and 完 that has somehow evaded me?

Comment: 全部 means all, it does not mean complete in most situations.

Comment: ok thank you, I just have a dictionary to refer to but I can't expect it to be perfect

Answer (score 1):

完in完本 means completed, for example 写完了功課 means the homework is completed
全部作品 means all of the works

The difference is that I can be writing 3 books at the same time, but none of them is completed, so these 3 books are my 全部作品, but none of them is 完本